# Microsoft word how to reference a translation?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, citations

I need to use the Harvard referencing scheme in a word document.

I need to add a source which is a translation (by Kenneth McLeish) of an originally Norwegian play (*A Doll's House* by Henrik Ibsen.)

How do I do that?

I see no options for translator or original language. I'm looking for the automatic insertion of a source like:

> Ibsen, H. 1879. *A Doll's House*. Translated from the Norwegian, by K. McLeish. ...

[image: Word's sources pane]

Comment: Select the **Show All Bibliography Fields** check box near the bottom to access more fields. Perhaps there are fields for translator information there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ticking the **Show All Bibliography Fields** box should expand the window and allow for addition of translators.